# How to add choice in mcq using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create program that able to create mcq. Below is my code

```
<p>how many mcq choice you need?</p>
<input type="text" id="question"></input>
```

Now im trying to use javascript to retrieve the input from the textbox. If the input is 4, it will appear

> a
>
> b
>
> c
>
> d

How would the javascript look like that i need to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried something that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function CreateMCQ(){
           document.getElementById('option').innerHTML = "";
           var input = document.getElementById('question').value ;
           for(var i = 0;i<input;i++){
               document.getElementById('option').innerHTML += "<input type='radio'>"+"option "+(i+1)+"<br/> ";
           }
       }
  </script>
```

html

```
    <p>how many mcq choice you need?</p>
    <input type="text" id="question"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="CreateMCQ();" />
    <div id="option"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
function check () {
    if (document.getElementById('question').value == 4)  {
    document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML += "a </br> b </br> c </br> d </br>"
    }
}
```

Bind this function in **`onchange`** event.

Comment: why a downvote? I have a working fiddle too http://jsfiddle.net/x9Xe8/